# webpack producing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle.js:1

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I'm a bit confused on what this issue may be. I've deleted bundle.js thinking by creating a new one would resolve the issue (Someone stated it in a different question), but that didn't happen. The error I'm getting is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundle.js:1
```

which points to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I've seen other forms people mentioning this error is to do with a 404 return of the html file. I was hoping someone can tell me if my webpack output is wrong. Within my html file I have

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
```

and my webpack is

```
let path = require("path");
let webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  entry: "./index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["react", "env"],
            plugins: ["emotion"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: [/\.scss$/, /\.css$/],
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "svg-inline-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          "file-loader",
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
              disable: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.csv$/,
        loader: "csv-loader",
        options: {
          dynamicTyping: true,
          header: true,
          skipEmptyLines: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ttf-loader",
            options: {
              name: "./font/[hash].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".scss", ".png"] },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/javascripts",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    })
  ]
};
```

If someone has seen this before and found a solution to it. I would love to learn why it has occurred and how to avoid this in the future.

Thank you again for all the help and teaching.

[UPDATE]

Here is an image of the error and what it shows when I click on bundle.js:1

[Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtkho.png)

Image under is my network

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwgsE.png)

[UPDATE!!!]
I've been wondering how come I'm seeing two bundle and notice the one within the body has a wrong path. Does anyone know where this came from? I don't see it in mny html file. This is an image of it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqQIV.png)

Comment: it would be good if you can share more of the error logs.. if any

Comment: @user1645290 I've updated and added a picture showing the error that appears.

Comment: Looks like webpack is not transpiling the react code properly. Could you try remove the `options` from the `babel-loader` and see if it works then?

Comment: @Jackson When I tried removing it, the entire application breaks and it is trying to read React components. I think the options are required for my application.

Comment: whether your bundle.js is getting generated. I could see bundle.js and build.js. Are you pointing the correct file.

Comment: As you have pointed yourself , you are probably requesting a js/json file but receiving an html document(probably caused by a 404).  can you send an image of your network tab inside the chrome dev tools?

Comment: @user1645290 I noticed that. I went to my webpack.config, deleted build.js and made it to create bundle.js. The issue still persists. I can't see any build.js anywhere in my app at the moment so I think I am point in the right location.

Comment: @OsvaldoMaria I updated the question with an image showing network.

Comment: It would you good to update the webpack file with the updated changes

Comment: @user1645290 Just updated it. Thanks :)

Comment: check this link if that solution helps.. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/205

Comment: @user1645290 I gave it a shot. But still the same error. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: On your js script source, try using a relative root reference.

Comment: @TimMoses I'm sorry if I misunderstood, do you mean something like this src="/src/javascripts/bundle.js" ?

Comment: @TimMoses I tried it that way and even added a base to the html but the error still continues.

Comment: @TimMoses I uploaded a new picture. I think the problem might be there. What do you think? because the path from that second random bundle is wrong.

Comment: @user1645290 I uploaded a picture where I think the error may be showing up. I noticed there are two bundles present (not sure why) but the second one path is wrong since there isn't any /js/ folder.

Comment: I think you found your issue...

Comment: bundle.js will be automatically added to the index.html.you dont need to add it manually.but not sure of the path from where it is coming from

Comment: @user1645290 Yup. That is what I needed to do, basically remove it since it was automatically being generated. Thank you :)

Comment: @TimMoses Yea. A minot error that took hours to solve haha Thank you for your help. I removed it from my html since as user1645290 has stated, it'll be automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have referenced a local js or ts file in your html page that does not exist on disk.

```
<script src="doesThisFileExist.js"></script>
```